# Running protractor scripts on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, protractor

I need to integrate my protractor scripts on Jenkins . My code is in Bit bucket and i configured the details on my project in Jenkins.

My Jenkins server is on Linux so i have used Execute shell .

Below are the steps i mentioned in execute shell in order to run.

```
npm install
webdriver-manager update
webdriver-manager start
protractor conf.js

Initialising WebDriverServlet
20:23:34.444 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 4444
```

Selenium server is up and running but it got stuck there and unable to execute next step.

.................................

I have also tried executing

```
npm install
protractor conf.js
```

by commenting selenium address on conf.js

For which m getting the below error

```
 I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[20:02:30] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[20:02:32] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at .........
Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
```

I need help on how to run the scripts on jenkins. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in adavnce

Answer (score 0):

I can tell what your problem is, but nor ready to provide a solution

so when you run `webdriver-manager start` it starts a process. When that process is running, you can't run another one, until you exit this one. When you do it manually, you're using 2 terminal windows, right?

so theoretical solution - you need to look up how to run commands in parallel on linux and this page has many https://www.slashroot.in/how-run-multiple-commands-parallel-linux

Another option that I'm using is to set `directConnect: true` in config file. This way you don't even need to start a server, protractor will do it for you. And honestly I don't know why not everyone is using it...

Comment: Thank you .I even tried that option . Started selenium server in background , commented Selenium address on conf.js file and  added DirectConnect : True and finally added 2 steps in  my jenkins file " npm install " , " protractor con.js "   I am getting below error [21:37:01] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[21:37:01] E/direct - Error code: 135
[21:37:01] E/direct - Error message: browserName Chrome is not supported with directConnect.
[21:37:01] E/direct - Error: browserName Chrome is not supported with directConnect.
    at Direct.setupDriverEnv

Comment: I bet its because it should be lower case @SailajaChikkam I use chrome with directconnect and it works

Comment: I used the same                                             browserName: 'chrome',

Comment: @SailajaChikkam can you post your full config file

Comment: var path = require('path');
exports.config = {
 //seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',   
    specs: ['./Scripts/test.js'],
    capabilities: {
     browserName: 'chrome',
     directConnect: 'true',
        chromeOptions: {
            
            prefs: {
             download: {
               'prompt_for_download': false,
               'default_directory': downloadsPath,
               'directory_upgrade': true
             },
           },
          //args: [ "--headless" ]
    }
    },
};

Comment: I am unable to upload full config file .. so i removed few sections (like reporting etc ) and posted

Comment: `directConnect` should be a property of config itself, not of `capabilities` like this `exports.config = {
 specs: ['./Scripts/test.js'],
 directConnect: 'true',
 capabilities: {`

Comment: Actually applied in config itself .. Then i got "browserName Chrome is not supported with directConnect." So i added inside capabilities

Comment: I am getting below error , As my jenkins server is on linux       
[17:46:22] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[17:46:22] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[17:46:23] E/launcher - session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 83
  (Driver info: chromedriver=83.0.4103.39 (ccbf011cb2d2b19b506d844400483861342c20cd-refs/branch-heads/4103@{#416}),platform=Linux 4.15.0-1042-azure x86_64)
[17:46:23] E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 83

Comment: Any comments on how to resolve this issue on Linux server @Sergey Pleshakov